# How to toggle-off the react-native-elements tooltip from another component

Tags: tooltip, react-native-elements, react-native-component

I want to manually close the tooltip but there are no documents on the react-native-elements site.

So I look over the tooltip code from github and noticed that it has a toggleTooltip function to toggle. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work.

This is the sample code for the tooltip

```
import { Tooltip } from 'react-native-elements';

render() {
  return (
    <Tooltip 
      ref="tooltip"
      popover={
        <ComponentTest
          toggle={this.refs.tooltip} 
        >
    >
      <Text>Click me</Text>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

The sample code for the ComponentTest

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

toggleOff = () => {
  this.props.toggleTooltip;
}

render() {
  return (
      <Button
        title="hide"
        type="outline"
        onPress={this.toggleOff}
      />
  );
}
```

And this is the function from the tooltip.js that I am trying to use. The full code of the tooltip can found here https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/tooltip/Tooltip.js

```
toggleTooltip = () => {
  const { onClose } = this.props;
  this.getElementPosition();
  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (prevState.isVisible && !isIOS) {
      onClose && onClose();
    }

    return { isVisible: !prevState.isVisible };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i am new to react-native and was trying to use tooltip, what i found out that whenever u click inside the component which is popovered , it navigates to whatever onpress function u have written on that particular component and the tooltip doesn't closes,,it also remain mounted when u navigate to other pages,,one solution to it is that use react-native-popup-menu.its the best that we can use for now as a tooltip  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-menu

Answer (score 0):

It may be a stupid solution, but did you tried using `this.props.toggleTooltip()` ?

OH , and ref is not a string anymore, it's a function

```
<Tooltip 
      ref={ref => (this.tooltip = ref)}
      popover={
        <ComponentTest
          toggle={this.tooltip} 
        >
    >
```

Comment: Both didn't work out. It produces an error{ undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props.toggle.toggleTooltip') }

Comment: mmm it may be nested, in line 239 it has `export default withTheme(Tooltip, 'Tooltip');` , the withTheme may be acting as a parent class and the function is one level below. You need to try doing `console.log(Object.keys(this.tooltip))`. And check one by one the keys to see wich one has the tootltip class

Comment: Error{Requested keys of a value that is not an object.}

Comment: mmm interesting . i don't think that console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tooltip)) would work... do console.log(this.tooltip) .. or maybe, file an issue in react-native-elements of how to open the tooltip programatically. Maybe the creator of the tooltip answers you

Comment: Console.log(this.tooltip) only produces undefined. I'll try asking them then. thanks for the time

Comment: it should not have undefined.. that means that you don't have a reference to the tooltip. It's either a bad implementation of `ref` , or maybe... you are using it inside ComponentTest wich doesn't have this.tooltip defined ... use it in the  same class where you have the tooltip, not in the child

Answer (score 0):

On line 191 of [Tooltip.js](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/tooltip/Tooltip.js):

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleTooltip}>
     {this.renderContent(true)}
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

and in the definition of renderContent:112 on line 137, it is rendered your popover: 
Thus wherever you touch in your popover will make it disappear. I don't know how to disable this behaviour, but I still want to know if and how the visibility of the popover can be controlled from the Tooltip's child element at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just set its style to `display:'none'` after you touch your popover.

maybe try this way:

```js
state = { theDisplay: 'flex' };

...

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any) {
    if (!prevProps.isFocused && this.props.isFocused) {
      this.setState({ theDisplay: 'flex' });
    }
}

...

<Popover.Item
    value={'response'}
    onSelect={() => {
        this.setState({ theDisplay: 'none' });
        navigate('NoticeResponse', { id: item.id });
    }}>
    <Text style={styles.toolsItem}>已读信息</Text>
</Popover.Item>
```

This is my own way of dealing with it. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER** I used the `ref` example in order to get my code to work, but it's something like this:

```
const tooltipRef = useRef(null);

const foo = (event, index) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  tooltipRef.current.toggleTooltip()
}
...
<Tooltip
  height={200}
  ref={tooltipRef}
  popover={<TouchableOpacity onPress={(event) => foo(event, index)}
/>
```

I had originally tried to implement this by simply using the `tooltipRef.current.toggleTooltip()` like in the [example](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/tooltip.html#toggletooltip-example) but it never ended up working because the event was propagating and continuing to toggle it on its own (effectively toggling it twice).

Answer (score 0):

Without any 3rd party library, simple tooltip for both iOS and android can be implemented as follows:

```
onPress={() =>
  Alert.alert("My Title", "My Msg", [], {
    cancelable: true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React native elements documentation show that we can manually turn off the tooltip.

[Docs](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/tooltip/#interaction-methods)

Store a reference to the Tooltip in your component by using the ref prop provided by React

```
const tooltipRef = useRef(null);

...

<Tooltip
    ref={tooltipRef}
  ...
/>
```

Then you can manually trigger tooltip from anywhere for example when screen loads:

```
useEffect(() => {
   tooltipRef.current.toggleTooltip();
}, []);
```

Comment: I can't get this to work which version are you using? I'm on v 3.4.2